# Nested generic containers with wildcard parameters?

Tags: java, generics

To understand generics in java i wrote the following code.

The question is - how should I parametrize `myBox` so that it would accept `FilterType <?> myFilterType` ?

```
public class Generics {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Generics g = new Generics();
        Object myValue = "putThisIntoTheBox";

        FilterType<?> myFilterType3   = g.new FilterType<>(null); //works
        Box myBox3                      = g.create(myFilterType3, myValue); //fails - create won't accept myFilterType3
    }

    public <T> Box<T> create(FilterType<T> type, T value) {
        return new Box<T>(value);
    }

    //CLASSES

    public class FilterType<T>{
        T type;
        public FilterType(T type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    public class Box<T>{
        T value;
        public Box(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `FilterType<?>` makes no sense when `FilterType` itself isn't generic. Likewise `FilterType` and `Box` make no sense as they include fields of type `T` but without saying anything about what `T` is. Surely they should be generic.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: Sure this doesn't make sence, but it's just an example. I would expect, that under type erasure everything would drop down to Object, but `FilterType<?>` seems not to be the same as `FilterType<Object>`

Comment: @greuze I am trying to understand generics

Comment: The proble seems to be that i declared in `create(FilterType<T> type, T value)` the FilterType parameter to be the same, as Type of value. Since the parrameter of `FilterType<?>` is a wildcard  - create waits for `? value`  - which does not exists. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `create` method expects consistent types for `FilterType<T> type` and `T value` parameters.

Here the value is declared as an `Object` instance, thus it expects type T generic to be an Object instance too.

Declaring `FilterType<Object> myFilterType3` solves the issue.

Comment: Doesn't the `?` do fallback to `Object` ? I thought `List<?>` and `List<? extends Object>` would be the same?

Comment: Not when compared with another method parameter, using generics from another class or method declaration. :(

Comment: @Skip: No, `?` means you don't know what it is. It could be `Object`, `String`, `SomeBogusType`, etc. Your code must work without assuming it's any particular type.